# Spin.js, Using .delay() and stopping a spinner

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, delay

I'm using [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/) for a spinner on a page. There is a small [jquery plugin](https://gist.github.com/1290439) that calls the spinner and also stops it. My problem is getting the spinner to stop after a delay. The spinner won't load with my delay code to stop it.
 Here is my code:

```
$("#loaderIcon").spin({
lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
length: 7, // The length of each line
width: 4, // The line thickness
radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
speed: 1, // Rounds per second
trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
shadow: false // Whether to render a shadow

});
$("#loaderIcon").delay(3000).spin(false);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) only works for the animation queue - it does not, as it might seem to, block for the provided time.  You should use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) if the delay does not need to block:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("#loaderIcon").spin(false); }, 3000);
```